# osascript and sudo password entry

Tags: macos, bash, osascript

I am using osascript in a BASH script for dialog boxes on a MAC system. The problem I am having is several of the commands I need to use require privilages to function correct. If I use sudo in the BASH script, the password prompt shows in the terminal window. Is the some way I can hook the sudo password prompt into an osascript dialog box? Or is there a different way I can handle asking for the password in an osascript dialog box and passing it to some other program to handle it?

Comment: See [this Apple.SE question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23494/what-option-should-i-give-the-sudo-command-to-have-the-password-asked-through-a).

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to create the BASH script and then use osascript to call it.

```
$ osascript -e 'do shell script "/Path/yourbashscript.sh" with administrator privileges'
```

This will prompt a dialog box straight from Apple's infrastructure. Same one you see when you're asked for your username & password.

You can run this in terminal or use a third-party wrapper like, [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the password interface by modifying your Mac's authorization rights.

Use the built-in [security](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/security.html) command line tool or authbuddy to change the system.preferences.accessibility right to allow:

```
sudo security authorizationdb write system.preferences.accessibility allow
```

Opening up the [system.preferences.accessibility](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/system-preferences-accessibility.html) right will permit any user to change the accessibility settings without a password prompt.

Comment: Unfortunatly this script is going to be given to customesrs, so modifying their system preferences is not an option
I want them to enter thier password., but I want to use an osascript dialog box to do it, and not in the terminal window, like it is currently working