# Make osascript execute in parent bash

Tags: bash, sudo, osascript

I want to extend the sudo timeout using GUI on my Mac for a script which contains sudo commands but is not allowed to run with root in total.

so I want to do something like:

```
osascript -e "do shell script 'sudo -v'" with administrator privileges"
do_some_thing_without_root
sudo do_some_thing_with_root_but_without_asking_the_password
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752365/osascript-and-sudo-password-entry) ?

Comment: Actually no. There you execute everything in this osascript environment with admin priveileges. I want to unlock the sudo in the osascripts parent bash environment. So that I can execute a script that forbids running as root but contains sudo commands...